# How to get my Delphi application to ignore windows touch screen keyboard in Windows 10

Tags: windows, delphi, keyboard, touch

Does anyone know of a way to get a Delphi application to ignore the windows touch screen keyboard selectively. I have an application that has its own (for very good reasons) on screen keyboards for all user interface controls that require textural input. But the application also has a embedded chromium browser page and for that I would like the windows pop up keyboard to surface when a user focuses an edit control within its pages.

I have tried a lot of the suggestions on the net and none have worked so far. What I have noticed is that the "Show the touch keyboard when not in tablet mode and there's no keyboard attached" option in Typing\Settings does exactly what I want. Only problem is how can I control that, or get the same affect programmatically?

That option sets a registry key HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\TabletTip\1.7\EnableEmbeddedInkControl to 0 or 1

I can do this from my Delphi application but unfortunately it doesn't have the same affect on the windows virtual keyboard that changing the settings from the windows settings application does. So I guess the Windows settings application is doing something more than just changing the registry key. Any ideas as to what its doing and if that can be replicated by my application.

Been looking at this a while now and its driving me nuts tbh :-)

J

Comment: just a guess: maybe it will help to send a broadcast message that the windows settings have changed after doing your changes to the registry: sendmessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, 0);

Comment: Hi thankyou so much Andre you were quite right. I used "SendMessageNotify" to broadcast this message after setting the registry value and it worked.